# First payment after subscription a plan delayed one day

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am implementing a payment subsystem with the REST API and recurring payments.

I have created several plans and when I make a subscription to one of these plans, the first payment it's done the day after I subscribe the plan. I expected to receive the first payment at the same moment I subscribe the plan. Why it's waiting for next day to do it?

At the moment I am using the sandbox.

Can somebody help me to achieve the behaviour I expected for the first payment when subscribe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mailed PayPal MTS and they answered me that for the moment it's not possible to do a inicial instant charge when you create a subscription using the REST API.

You can do it with the Classic API setting up the optional INITAMT from the Activation Details Fields.

You can get more details here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/

Comment: You could also use the `setup_fee` field.